# How to move an image on click in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am new to JavaFX and I would like to create Lloyds fifteen game(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle).
I created controler for the game but I cant see a way to connect it with some drawing pane. I´d like to move elements on click.

edit: I´d need help with choosing right pane to draw elements(should they extend something?), that would be clickable.

Controler: 
it creates matrix of elements. it provides basic methods to shuffle the board and to move a single element(those methods check, if zero(=blank field) is next to this element, then the element can move). finally it has method to check, if the puzzle is in final state(all elements are in their final positions)

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LloydsFifteen {

  Element[][] actualState;
  int[] zeroPosition;
  int countInARow;
  int numberOfDrags;

  //for Lloyds fifteen, countInARow will be 4
  public LloydsFifteen(int countInARow)
  {
      numberOfDrags = 0;

      this.countInARow = countInARow;
      actualState = new Element[countInARow][countInARow];
      zeroPosition = new int[2];

      zeroPosition[0] = countInARow-1;
      zeroPosition[1] = countInARow-1;

      for(int i = 0; i < countInARow; i++)
      {         
          for(int j = 0; j < countInARow; j++)
          {
              actualState[i][j] = new Element(i*countInARow + j);


          }

      }

      shuffleLloyd(100000);

      for(int i = 0; i < countInARow; i++)
      {         
          for(int j = 0; j < countInARow; j++)
          {
              System.out.println("prvek na pozici [" + i + ", " + j + "] ma id: " + 
                      actualState[i][j].finalPosition + " a aktualni pozici: " + actualState[i][j].actualPosition );


          }

      }

      System.out.println("a pozice nuly je [" + zeroPosition[0] + ", " + zeroPosition[1] + "]" );
      System.out.println("a pocet provedenych tahu je " + numberOfDrags);

  }

  //shuffles the board
  public void shuffleLloyd(int pocetTahu)
  {
      Random r = new Random();

      for(int i = 0; i < pocetTahu; i++)
      {

          switch(r.nextInt(4))
          {
              case 0: if(moveRight()) numberOfDrags++; break;
              case 1: if(moveLeft()) numberOfDrags++; break;
              case 2: if(moveUp()) numberOfDrags++; break;
              case 3: if(moveDown()) numberOfDrags++; break;
              default: break;

          }

          //another way to shuffle the board
          //moveAnElement(r.nextInt(4), r.nextInt(4));


      }



  }

  //checks, if element can be moved
  public void moveAnElement(int x, int y)
  {
      boolean done = false;

      if(zeroPosition[0] == x + 1 && zeroPosition[1] == y)
      {
          done = moveRight();   
      }

      if(zeroPosition[0] == x - 1 && zeroPosition[1] == y)
      {
          done = moveLeft();
      }

      if(zeroPosition[0] == x && zeroPosition[1] == y + 1)
      {
          done = moveDown();
      }

      if(zeroPosition[0] == x && zeroPosition[1] == y - 1)
      {
          done = moveUp();
      }

      if(done)
      {
          //System.out.println("Pohyb se vydaril"); 
          numberOfDrags++;
      }

  }

  public boolean moveRight()
  {
      Element tmp;
      boolean done = false;

      if(zeroPosition[0] > 0)
      {
          tmp = actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1]];
          actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1]] = actualState[zeroPosition[0] - 1][zeroPosition[1]];
          actualState[zeroPosition[0] - 1][zeroPosition[1]] = tmp;

          zeroPosition[0] = zeroPosition[0] - 1;
          done = true;
      }

      if(checkEndOfGame())
      {
          System.out.println("Gratuluji k nalezeni reseni");

      }

      return done;

  }


  public boolean moveLeft()
  {
      Element tmp;
      boolean done = false;

      if(zeroPosition[0] < countInARow - 1)
      {
          tmp = actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1]];
          actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1]] = actualState[zeroPosition[0] + 1][zeroPosition[1]];
          actualState[zeroPosition[0] + 1][zeroPosition[1]] = tmp;

          zeroPosition[0] = zeroPosition[0] + 1;
          done = true;
      }

      if(checkEndOfGame())
      {
          System.out.println("Gratuluji k nalezeni reseni");

      }

      return done;
  }


  public boolean moveDown()
  {
      Element tmp;
      boolean done = false;

      if(zeroPosition[1] > 0)
      {
          tmp = actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1]];
          actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1]] = actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1] - 1];
          actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1] - 1] = tmp;

          zeroPosition[1] = zeroPosition[1] - 1;
          done = true;
      }

      if(checkEndOfGame())
      {
          System.out.println("Gratuluji k nalezeni reseni");

      }

      return done;

  }


  public boolean moveUp()
  {
      Element tmp;
      boolean done = false;

      if(zeroPosition[1] < countInARow - 1)
      {
          tmp = actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1]];
          actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1]] = actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1] + 1];
          actualState[zeroPosition[0]][zeroPosition[1] + 1] = tmp;

          zeroPosition[1] = zeroPosition[1] + 1;
          done = true;
      }

      if(checkEndOfGame())
      {
          System.out.println("Gratulations");

      }

      return done;

  }

  //checks if all elements are in final positions
  private Boolean checkEndOfGame()
  {

      for(int i = 0; i < countInARow; i++)
      {         
          for(int j = 0; j < countInARow; j++)
          {
              if(actualState[i][j].finalPosition != (i*countInARow + j))
              {
                  return false;                                     
              }
          }         
      }

      return true;
  }
}
```

and an Element

```
public class Element {

    int finalPosition;
    int actualPosition;

    //position is j*numberInARow + i
    public Element(int finalPosition)
    {
        this.finalPosition = finalPosition;
        this.actualPosition = finalPosition;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any hint, I have no idea about next step.
I want it to look like this: [Lloyds fifteen puzzle http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~kjg/cs123/Labs/raster/15.gif](http://www.cse.wustl.edu/~kjg/cs123/Labs/raster/15.gif)
Elements will be part of image(user chooses an image, i will split it and create those elements)

Comment: Your question is not very well explained. You dump a big piece of code and do not explain what the Lloyds fifteen game does. Further it is not exactly clear what you want to do. Please explain in more detail, by editing your question.

Comment: I hope all the information is there now. Actually main problem is to choose drawing pane in javaFX(Pane or Canvas?) and creating an element, that could move fluently. Logic of the game I will add, main problem for me is choosing right classes of JavaFX

Comment: Here you will find a puzzle example in same login with your game http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/products/javafx/2/samples/Ensemble/index.html

Comment: thanks, thats great!

Answer (score 1):

The next step is to setup the UI, the Application which basically is the thread you will start first. For layout I suggest you use a `GridPane` of 4x4 and initialize it with the `Element` matrix.

Take a look at [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/JavaFX/0340__JavaFX_GridPane.htm) of a `GridPane` for a simple form and of course the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html).

The next steps then would be to add event handlers so that the elements can be reassigned to a different position (that will call the various move methods).

Comment: is it possible to move elements fluently in GridPane? I mean fluently translating element(image) between cells

Comment: You can create a method which will remove the `ImageView` node from one grid cell and add it to the other.

Comment: I am not sure, if u got my point. I need ImageView to move fluently, not just remove it from one cell and add it to another.

Comment: You do not need the `ImageView` to move it, but as you want to use a cut up image instead of simple numbers, those sub `Image` must be added to the grid by means of an `ImageView`.

Comment: @DanielŠvarc You can use a [`TranslateTransition`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/TranslateTransition.html) to animate the elements (I think this is what you mean). You might find it's easier to use a plain `Pane` and position them yourself if you want to animate them, instead of using a `GridPane`. The Oracle tutorial has a section on [animation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/visual-effects-tutorial/animations.htm#JFXTE149).